# Why two definitions of convolution are not equivalent?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, functional-analysis, analysis, convolution

In half of the textbooks the convolution operation is defined as
$$
(f * g)(x) = \int_{\mathbb{R}^d} f(x - y) g(y) dy
$$
whereas in the other half, it is defined as
$$
(f * g)(z) = \int_{\mathbb{R}^d} f(w) g(z - w) dw.
$$
However it seems to me these two are not equivalent? Indeed in the first case, if I substitute $z = x - y$ then I get a minus in front since $dy = -dz$
$$
(f*g)(x) = - \int_{\mathbb{R}^d}f(z) g(x - z) dz
$$

Comment: You also have to change the integration limits

Comment: There is a misprint in the second formula: should be $f(w)$ instead $f(z).$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For an arbitary $d$  you make the substitution $w=x-y.$ The Jacobian matrix is equal $-I.$ The absolute value of its determinant is equal $1.$ Therefore you obtain  $$(f*g)(x)=\int\limits_{\mathbb{R}^d}  f(x-y)\,g(y)\,dy=
\int\limits_{\mathbb{R}^d}  f(w)\,g(x-w)\,dw$$

Answer (score 1):

The two definitions are equivalent. Take $d = 1$ for the sake of simplicity. We have
\begin{align}
(f \star g)(x) &= \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x - y) g(y)dy\\
&= -\int_{\infty}^{-\infty} f(z) g(x - z)dz\\
&= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(z) g(x - z)dz
\end{align}

Comment: oh my god of course, the limits of integration!

Comment: How would you do this for $d > 1$?

Comment: Just remember that
$$\int_{\mathbb R^2}f = \int_{-\infty}^\infty\int_{-\infty}^\infty f$$